# Пропала библиотека configparser

Tags: python, парсер, config

Изучаю питон, работаю с библиотекой конфигпарсер. До этого код писал в атоме все работало нормально, перешел на visual studio. Появилась ошибка `AttributeError: module 'configparser' has no attribute 'configparser'`. Переустановка библиотеки не помогла. Как это исправить и в дальнейшем пользоваться библиотекой?
Сделаю поправку. безуспешно переустановил питон 3.6.8

Comment: возможно вы создали файл configparser.py в папке проекта

Answer (score 1):

Хочу ответить на свой же вопрос. Спасибо @eri и тому форумчанину который говорил что вероятно configparser обновился и нужно использовать ConfigParser вместо configparser. Проблему мне решить помогла полная переустановка питон. Файл configparser.py я и правда нашел в папке  visual studio, но его удаление приводило к проблемам с pip, почему я так и не понял. Видимо где то нарушились пути к библиотеке. А после переустановки питона configparser и правда обновился и я пол часа пытался обращаться к библиотеке по старому :DD.